# Cobol - Importing a signed numeric with real decimal

Tags: cobol

I'm having trouble getting my batch to correctly interpret the values in a file I'm reading.

The values have a separate leading sign and a real decimal, eg:

```
;+000000123.99;+123456789.99;
```

But the following just gives me compilation errors:

```
10 FILLER     PIC X(1).
10 VALUE1     PIC S9(9),9(2) SIGN LEADING SEPARATE.
10 FILLER     PIC X(1).
10 VALUE2     PIC S9(9),9(2) SIGN LEADING SEPARATE.
10 FILLER     PIC X(1).
```

In this shop, they use DECIMAL POINT IS COMMA

I thought I'd be able to just define a numerical as above and just read the file without any extra work, but can't seem to get it to work.

If I use a implied decimal I don't get an error.

Isn't it possible to mix sign leading separate and real decimal?

Comment: +1 for asking a Cobol question.

Comment: @zmbq that's 530 COBOL questions. You Upvoted them all?

Comment: OK, so what error are you getting?

Comment: Just the ones I see...

Comment: I was thinking you might like to show them to us :-)

Comment: Is it a fixed width file with or are the ';' field separators ???

Comment: It has been a while since I worked on the mainframe, but from what I remember for values like +000000123.99 you may need / be better off using a routine to convert it to a numeric value

Comment: Updated answer, may affect you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This bit is quite important.

Firstly, I'll show how I do this. I do it this way, because I like to know that everything which should have a particular value does have that particular value.

```
       05  VALUE-TO-DE-EDIT. 
           10  VTDE-SIGN                   PIC X. 
               88  VTDE-SIGN-VALID         VALUE "-" "+". 
               88  VTDE-NEGATIVE           VALUE "-". 
           10  VTDE-INTEGER-PART           PIC X(9). 
           10  VTDE-DEC-POINT              PIC X. 
               88  VTDE-DEC-POINT-VALID    VALUE ".". 
           10  VTDE-DECIMAL-PART           PIC XX. 
   01  THE-NUMBER                          PIC S9(9)V99. 
   01  FILLER REDEFINES THE-NUMBER. 
       05  TN-INTEGER-PART                 PIC X(9). 
  * The S in the PICture is required, to get correct sign for a
  * positive edited value, unless you do it a different way.
  * 
       05  TN-DECIMAL-PART                 PIC S99.
```

And then in the `PROCEDURE DIVISION`, the details, of course, can vary, this is only an example keeping it short and minimum:

```
       IF ( VTDE-SIGN-VALID 
        AND VTDE-DEC-POINT-VALID 
        AND VTDE-INTEGER-PART NUMERIC 
        AND VTDE-DECIMAL-PART NUMERIC ) 
           PERFORM                  DE-EDIT-NUMBER 
           DISPLAY THE-NUMBER 
       ELSE 
           PERFORM                  BUSTED-NUMBER 
       END-IF 
       IF ( VTDE-SIGN-VALID 
        AND VTDE-DEC-POINT-VALID 
        AND VTDE-INTEGER-PART NUMERIC 
        AND VTDE-DECIMAL-PART NUMERIC ) 
           PERFORM                  DE-EDIT-NUMBER 
           DISPLAY THE-NUMBER 
       ELSE 
           PERFORM                  BUSTED-NUMBER 
       END-IF 
       ... 
   DE-EDIT-NUMBER. 
       MOVE VTDE-INTEGER-PART       TO TN-INTEGER-PART 
       MOVE VTDE-DECIMAL-PART       TO TN-DECIMAL-PART 
       IF VTDE-NEGATIVE 
           SUBTRACT THE-NUMBER      FROM ZERO 
             GIVING                 THE-NUMBER 
       END-IF 
       . 
   BUSTED-NUMBER. 
       do what you feel
       .
```

OK, why am I showing that now after you Accepted the Answer?

You were attempting your solution with a `SEPARATE SIGN` and without validating the data. Without validating the data, the easiest thing to do is to "de-edit" the edited number. The compiler does it all for you, you just code one MOVE. If the sign is "wrong", you'll get a run-time error. If the decimal-point value is "wrong" nothing will happen. If your elements of the number are not numeric, you'll get some slightly-garbled version of them. To do it that way, you have to 100% trust the numbers. Data from external files and from reports I *always* validate.

OK, you are `DECIMAL POINT IS...`

Change the S, which is not a sign for a numeric-edited field, to + and drop the `SIGN LEADING SEPARATE`. You should be good to go.

Unless you use `DECIMAL POINT IS COMMA` COBOL uses a full-stop/period/dot for a decimal-point.

Your data contains what COBOL would produce as a decimal-point, so just change your data-definitions to use `.` rather than `,`.

If you want to use the data, you can MOVE the numeric-edited field (that is what you have by having an explicit decimal-point) to a field with an implied decimal place.

Your definition will work as long as the data is in fixed positions. If the "widths" vary within a column, you will have a different problem with a different solution.

Comment: @bek Thanks. I suggest you look back at this later in the day, I'll have an update to make at lunchtime. I think there is some undocumented behaviour with the general method I showed, so I'll show you the way I always do it :-)

Comment: Nice answer. Surprised you did not mention NUMVAL.